# Crafting a python dictionary based on a .properties file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, parsing, properties-file

I want to parse a .properties-file's keys and values into a python dictionary.
The .properties-file I'm parsing uses the following syntax (keys and values are examples):

```
key1.subkey1.subsubkey1=value1
key1.subkey1.subsubkey2=value2
key1.subkey2=value3
key2=value4
```

So each value corresponds to a key consisting of one or more levels divided with periods.
The goal is to create a Python dictionary where each key is a dictionary containing its value and subkeys. The dictionary should be recursively iterable, so each level should follow the same structure.

The previous example should result in the following kind of dictionary:

```
'subKeys': 
  'key1':
    'subKeys':
      'subkey1': 
        'subKeys':
          'subsubkey1': 
            'val': 'value1'
          'subsubkey2': 
            'val': 'value2'
      'subkey2': 
        'val': 'value3'
  'key2':
    'val': 'value4'
```

I'm looping it with the following algorithm in python:

```
def setKeyAndValue(storageDict, rowParts):
    keyParts = rowParts[0].split('.')
    if not keyParts[0] in outputDict:
        storageDict[keyParts[0]] = {}
    newObj = storageDict[keyParts[0]]
    for i in range(len(keyParts)):
        if i == len(keyParts)-1:
            # Reached the end of the key, save value to dictionary
            newObj["val"] = rowParts[1]
        else :
            # Not yet at the end of the key
            if "subKeys" not in newObj:
                newObj["subKeys"] = {}
            if keyParts[i+1] not in newObj["subKeys"]:
                newObj["subKeys"][keyParts[i+1]] = {}
            newObj = newObj["subKeys"][keyParts[i+1]]

f = open("FILEPATH.properties", "r")
outputDict = {}
outputDict["subKeys"] = {}
outputDictSubKeys = outputDict["subKeys"]
for row in f:
    if not row.startswith('#') and not row.startswith('//'):
        parts = row.split('=', 1)
        if  len(parts)== 2:
            setKeyAndValue(outputDictSubKeys, parts)  
f.close()
```

The resulting dictionary (outputDict) is missing two key-value pairs (key1.subkey1.subsubkey1=value1,
key1.subkey1.subsubkey2=value2):

```
'subKeys': 
  'key1':
    'subKeys':
      'subkey2': 
        'val': 'value3'
  'key2':
    'val': 'value4'
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is with the following row:

```
newObj = newObj["subKeys"][keyParts[i+1]]
```

I'm replacing newObj within the dictionary with each iteration of the loop.

Is there a way to tweak this existing algorithm to make it work, and if not, how should I start over? Efficiency is not an issue, the properties-file isn't very large.

Comment: What is test1 in your code?

Comment: Sorry about that, it was the original name of outputDict before I renamed it for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your function and test your code and made some changes. The below code is working fine.

```
def setKeyAndValue(storageDict, rowParts):
    print rowParts
    keyParts = rowParts[0].split('.')
    if not keyParts[0] in storageDict.keys():
            storageDict[keyParts[0]] = {}
    newObj = storageDict[keyParts[0]]
    for i in range(len(keyParts)):
            if i == len(keyParts)-1:
                    # Reached the end of the key, save value to dictionary
                    newObj["val"] = rowParts[1]
            else :
                    # Not yet at the end of the key
                    if "subKeys" not in newObj:
                            newObj["subKeys"] = {}
                    if keyParts[i+1] not in newObj["subKeys"]:
                            newObj["subKeys"][keyParts[i+1]] = {}
                    newObj = newObj["subKeys"][keyParts[i+1]]



def main():
    input  = [
            'key1.subkey1.subsubkey1=value1',
            'key1.subkey1.subsubkey2=value2',
            'key1.subkey2=value3',
            'key2=value4'
    ]
    ans = {}
    ans1 = {
            'subKeys': ans
    }

    for row in input:
            parts = row.split('=', 1)
            setKeyAndValue(ans, parts)
    print ans1

main()
```

Output is coming as:

```
{'subKeys': {'key2': {'val': 'value4'}, 'key1': {'subKeys': {'subkey2': {'val': 'value3'}, 'subkey1': {'subKeys': {'subsubkey1': {'val': 'value1'}, 'subsubkey2': {'val': 'value2'}}}}}}}
```

Replaced your `OutputDict` variable with `storageDict.keys()` and wrote a sample main function. Try running it for yourself and see if it is working for you.

What I think is your OutputDict contains only `subKeys` key so the condition will always be true and you will replace the previously added dictionary with a blank dictionary.

Comment: I have edited the comment. Try copy the code and put in a python file and run it yourself.

Comment: Thank you. Those changes solved the issue I was having.

Answer (score 1):

Some observations:

- The thing that you are trying to do is closely related to a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). You are generating common prefixes with a final value.
- For the nested structure, the built in [reduce](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reduce-in-python/) function from `functools`, will become very useful.

## Solution

### Data

Now assume that we have a file called `data.properties` with the following structure

```
key1.subkey1.subsubkey1=value1
key1.subkey1.subsubkey2=value2
key1.subkey2=value3
key2=value4
```

### Code

Then we can use the following code

```
import functools
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

if __name__ == '__main__':
    node = lambda: defaultdict(node)
    trie = node()

    with open("data.properties", 'r') as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            key, value = line.strip().split('=')
            functools.reduce(dict.__getitem__, key.split('.'), trie)

            val = (functools.reduce(lambda d, key: d.get(key), key.split('.')[:-1], trie))
            val[key.split('.')[-1]] = value

    pprint(trie)
```

### output

to generate the following output

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000002054579EF70>,
            {'key1': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000002054579EF70>,
                                 {'subkey1': defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000002054579EF70>,
                                                         {'subsubkey1': 'value1',
                                                          'subsubkey2': 'value2'}),
                                  'subkey2': 'value3'}),
             'key2': 'value4'})
```

Where the `defaultdict` can be ignored, as long as the key is in the dictionary. If you want to remove the `defaultdict` property, you can use this function

```
def defaultdict_to_dict(data):
    """ Convert a nested defaultdict to a normal dictionary.  """
    if isinstance(data, defaultdict):
        data = dict(data)
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for k, v in data.items():
            data[k] = defaultdict_to_dict(v)
    return data
```

And call it using `pprint(defaultdict_to_dict(trie))`.
which will output

```
{'key1': {'subkey1': {'subsubkey1': 'value1', 
                      'subsubkey2': 'value2'},
          'subkey2': 'value3'},
 'key2': 'value4'}
```

## Explanation

Most of the magic is happening in the following two lines

1)
`functools.reduce(dict.__getitem__, key.split('.'), trie)`

2)
`val = (functools.reduce(lambda d, key: d.get(key), key.split('.')[:-1], trie))`

In the first line, we are creating the Trie, for all the keys, and all the values (leaves) will be a `defaultdict`. This means that it can be extended arbitrary deep (have as many sub keys as you want).

In the second line we are traversing the Trie, by following the keys, up to the last key. Using `key1.subkey1.subsubkey1=value1` as an example, this code will be similar to

```
val = trie['key1']['subkey1']
```

Where the next line (`val[key.split('.')[-1]] = value`) is equal to

```
trie['key1']['subkey1']['subsubkey1'] = 'value1'
```

Comment: While this answer was informative and useful for future python development, I chose Sunny Jain's answer as it required the least amount of changes to my existing code. Thanks for the explanation!